# How do you use tzkt API lastactivity parametre?

Tags: api, tzkt

According to the documentation:

Int32Parameter (object) Nullable
Filters accounts by last activity level (where the account was updated)

But I'm not sure how to use an integer to specify a date or cycle. I'm trying to get a list of delegators who have been active in the last month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lastActivity` parameter is used to compare the level of the blockchain.

To get the list of active delegators within the last month, first, you'll need to get the block level that was applied just a month from now. You can use [Get Level By Timestamp query](https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Blocks_GetByDate2) to get the level at any particular time.
So, one month from the time of writing this answer is `2023-06-30T15:50:00Z` GMT. So, the query https://api.tzkt.io/v1/blocks/2023-06-30T15:50:00Z/level returns `3797616`.

Now, we can use `lastActivity.gt` to filter only those items which were active sometime later than the given timestamp. Hence, you can add `lastActivity.gt=3797616` to the query.